# Alter database design with JPA

Tags: database, jpa, ejb-3.0, managed-bean

I am working on database with JPA and i am curios about altering the database design. Lets say i have a table and i want to add/remove a column in that table.

I have tried with re-deploying technique but it did not work for me. I am using JPA 2.0

So, just want to know is there any standard way to alter database tables or manually add/remove table's design? Also is it possible to change the primary key of table ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-production DBs you can use the `persistence.xml` properties to either create, drop-create or just update the existing db schema (example for Hibernate):

```
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit ...>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

for EclipseLink, the property name is different and so are the available options:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
```

For production DBs however I would stick to manual changes as you have to be very careful about the details and the timing.

Comment: I am using eclipse and i have already this property set as follows:

Comment: <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>

Comment: do i need to change it to 'create-tables' ?

Comment: No, when your app is deployed, it will drop the tables, then recreate them.  Using create-tables will only create tables, and so will not work if the tables already exist.  You can use create-or-extend-tables if you don't want them dropped, but the changes it can handle are limited to add in new fields, not removing or changing existing columns